# Bootstrap Carousel with multiple items and slides in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am creating a bootstrap carousel in php. It is working, but not how I was hoping.

I created a sample on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86cwk8ee/).

Basically, the $list array contains multiple items. It can be a different number if items. Code is as below:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myFirstCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <?php $counter = 0;?>
                    <?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
                        <div class="item col-sm-3 <?php if ($counter == 1) echo 'active';?>">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $imageurl;?>" alt="<?php echo $imagealt;?>" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $counter++;?> 
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="control-box pager">
                        <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#myFirstCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a data-slide="next" href="#myFirstCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>         
            </div>
        </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am looking to achieve is to have the carousel display 4 items, each in a `col-md-3` div. The next slide should display the next 4 items, etc, until there are no more items to show. I got the idea from [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-moving-box-carousel) to display like this.

How would I achieve this in php? Currently, it only displays one col-sm-3 div with one item in it per slide. What do I need to change to make this display 4 items per slide?

Any insight? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your jsFiddle code into the question with [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: thanks @Peter I added a snippet.